# Раз, два, много...

Tags: лингвистика

У меня, может быть, глупый вопрос, но все равно интересно.
Существует много слов, где множественное число для двух-четырех единиц отличается от множественного для пяти и более. Есть даже заметка об очередном выносе мозга для иностранца, пытающегося сосчитать яйца: одно - яйцо, два - яйцА, пять - яиц, а много - яйца. Та же ситуация со словом "сердце": одно - сердце, два-четыре - сЕрдца, пять - сердец, а много - сердцА.
Откуда такая разница между количеством предметов?

Answer (score 1):

Это форма древнего двойственного числа, которого сейчас в языке уже нет. Но следы остались.